# Resume suspended emacs session in gui mode

Tags: user-interface, emacs

How to resume suspended session of emacs. Emacs session is suspended using C-z. when using emacs in terminal then we can resume using "fg" but when using emacs in gui mode then how to resume if it suspended.

Comment: My understanding is that in an `xemacs` window you pressed `Ctrl`+`C`. Is that correct?

Comment: @jcollado: Why do you think that? The question asks specifically about ctrl-Z.

Comment: @tripleee Sorry for the confusion, I mystyped `C` for `Z`. I was just trying to get more information from the OP.

Answer (score 2):

In GUI mode C-z simply minimizes Emacs - it doesn't actually suspend it.

Comment: What this means then depends on the window manager. Most window managers will represent the process with a button in the task bar or similar (good^W old `twm` would place an icon-like thing on the desktop) and you restore by clicking (or occasionally, I think e.g. in `twm`, double-clicking) that.

Comment: Sadly, most window managers don't have a scripting interface to restore a minimized window from a shell prompt. (Sawfish was very nice in this regard.)

Comment: My environment does not, it puts GUI emacs in the background.

Answer (score 1):

One idea to consider would be to run emacs in [daemon mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon).  All of your frames would share this one session.  Instead of starting emacs, you would start emacsclient which would then reconnect to that shared daemon process.

Comment: Emacsclient still gets stuck on C-z.